# geom_errorbar disappears when using scale_x_reverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am trying to produce a simple scatter plot but with the x scale reversed (as this will be a better way of showing that y declines with increasing x. The plot works fine with both axes ascending...

```
envsum$chemo.index <- c(0.56254404 2.73595615 2.47705543 0.01796475)

envsum$sp_shared <- c(66.6 100.0  83.9  62.8)

gShareSP  <- ggplot(envsum, aes(chemo.index, sp_shared))

gShareSP  <- gShareSP + geom_point()

gShareSP  <- gShareSP +  geom_errorbarh(xmax=ch.ind+seCh, xmin=ch.ind-seCh)

gShareSP  <- gShareSP + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, colour="black")

gShareSP  <- gShareSP + theme_bw()

gShareSP
```

but when I add the line

```
gShareSP  <- gShareSP + scale_x_reverse()
```

`errorbars` disappear (except one which moves to a random point on the plot)

I didn't think `scale_x_reverse` should alter the positions of the error bars and I can't find the fix to stop it happening

Comment: Problem persists with scale reversed using xlim(3,0)

Comment: Also affects y axis in same manner (i.e. points replotted but error bars lost)

Comment: Solved by ggplot2 google forum - errorbarh should be within aes 

gShareSP +  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=ch.ind+seCh, xmin=ch.ind-seCh))